# PHP Code Inserting Empty Records Into MySQL DB

Tags: php, mysql, forms

My code inserts an empty record into the MySQL table "table1" instead of getting what inserted in the field "Name" in form1.html. 
Any idea why it inserts an empty record instead of what the user entered in the field?

**form1.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd"
    >
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Insert Your Name</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h3> Insert Your Name</h3>
    <form action="form1.php" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="Name">
            <input type="Submit" value="Submit" name="Submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**form.php**

```
> <?php 
> $connection =
> mysql_connect("localhost","root","")
> or die ("Couldn't Connect To Server");
> $db = mysql_select_db("db1",
> $connection) or die ("Couldn't Select
> Database"); $query = "CREATE TABLE IF
> NOT EXISTS table1 (Name VARCHAR(20))";
> $result = mysql_query($query) or die
> ("Query Failed: " . mysql_error());
> $query = "INSERT INTO table1 (Name)
> VALUES ('$_post[Name]')"; $result =
> mysql_query($query) or die ("Query
> Failed: " . mysql_error()); $query =
> "SELECT * FROM table1"; $result =
> mysql_query($query) or die ("Query
> Failed: " . mysql_error());
>     echo "<TABLE BORDER = '1'>";
>     echo "<TR>";
>     echo "<TH>Name</TH>";
>     echo "</TR>";
>     
>     while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
>     {
>         echo "<TR>";
>         echo "<TD>", $row['name'], "</TD>";
>         echo "</TR>";
>     }
>     echo "</TABLE>";
>     mysql_close($connection); ?>
```

Comment: +1 seldom newbie with reputation 1 able to post question with great readability :)

Comment: Thanks ajreal! I hope this is the place I'll be able to find answers:)

Comment: Have you looked in the database to verify if the name field is being saved there? That will determine if the problem is in your insert or your select.

Comment: Not sure I understand, Surreal Dreams. Do you mean that I hsould check if the Name field is saved properly in the database? because it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 $query = "INSERT INTO table1 (Name)
 VALUES ('{$_POST[Name]}')"; $result =
 mysql_query($query) or die ("Query
 Failed: " . mysql_error());
```

`$_POST` and `$_GET` are uppercase.

change the display code to:

```
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
     {
         echo "<TR>";
         echo "<TD>", $row['Name'], "</TD>";
         echo "</TR>";
     }
```

Comment: Thanks to you to Horia! Wow, it's reall ynice how quickly stuff is answered around here. HoI will refer my second question to you too: the php code that shows a table with the data does not show the new recoed entered. Ideas?

Comment: also, try to keep all things lowercase in the future. Less headaches that way.

Comment: Works Perectly! Thanks Horia. So the problem is in the letter case, eh? Good to know.

Comment: When I get the reputation, when I get the reputation:)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
$query = "INSERT INTO table1 (Name) VALUES ('$_post[Name]')";
```

Try this

```
$query = "INSERT INTO table1 (Name) VALUES ('" .
          mysql_real_escape_string($_post['Name'],$db) . "')";
```

Comment: Thanks to you to Roy-same question as I asked Pradeep: the php code that shows a table with the data from "table1" does not show the new recoed entered. Ideas?

Comment: Propably it's the same problem: case.echo "<TD>", $row['Name'], "</TD>";

Answer (score 0):

Please change this

```
<input type="text" name="fname">


$query = "INSERT INTO table1 (Name)
 VALUES ('".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[fname],$db)."')";
```

Comment: However, there is a different problem now-the php code that shows a table with the data does not show the new recoed entered. Ideas?

Comment: after insert please redirect the page

Comment: Solved already, Pradeep, buy anyhow-what do you mean redirec the page? Should i build a new php file, and divide it to one that stores the data (ehich could be the HTML itself?) and one that shows the data?

Answer (score 0):

```
 " . ($_POST['Fname'] != "") ? $_POST['Fname'] : "No Name" ."
```

Comment: Thanks Geeo! What is the reason for the "No Name"? So if somebody inserted a blank field, that it would just write "no name"?